How to view the different values in a geopoint to a Data table in Kibana Elasticsearch Maps
I have different values in a single geo point in Kibana Elasticsearch map.
is it possible to get that values in table, with columns as same as from Tooltip, on a Dashboard??
In this image , I am having 17 values in a single point, How to get that values in a table , on a Dashboard?


I was able to do this , with the help of Discover tool in Kibana. I could select the columns I want and save it as a Saved search.
Then create a dashboard, load the Map, and load the Saved search to the Dashboard.
Then the filters you apply on the Map, will be reflected on the saved search.
